# gdb stepping into nested member functions a.getClassB().getClassC().SomeMethodInClassC();

Tags: c++, gdb

```
Class A; //Singleton
Class B; // Singleton
Class C; //Singleton

1.A a;
2.a.getClassB().getClassC().SomeMethodInClassC();
3.//Some other code
```

This steps into getClassB() function , then if I give step at return of getClassB() method , it directly goes to line 3 , instead of going to getClassC() method.

Is there any setting we need to modify in gdb ? Or am I missing anything ?

I tried googling but found nothing related to this type of function calls.

Comment: When debugging it's usually good to turn off all optimizations. You might want to recompile with `-O0` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all ensure SomeMethodInClassC is not inlined by the compiler and then
2. Set break-point when member function is hit using

   (gdb) break C::SomeMethodInClassC()

There are several docs available online. [This one](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html#BCPPFUNC) has got some examples